# DB2 date field export to flat file

Tags: db2, jcl

While exporting the date field to flat file using JCL, I am having 2 issues

```
Select char(orderdate) 
from orders
```

1. The date field is prefixed with `'..12-10-2001'`
2. The null field is exported as `'............'`

I tried `COALESCE(cast(orderdate as varchar(10),'NULL')`. I am getting the same results

Comment: can you include the JCL? without it, you may as well remove the JCL tag.

Comment: What is the data type of `orderdate`?

Comment: orderdate column datatype is date

Comment: What program are you using to export the data?

Comment: Side note: it would almost certainly be better to export your date field in a SARGable format, probably ISO: `YYYY-MM-DD`.